# Mutualy owned bi directional relations (friends)

Tags: hibernate, orm, ibatis

I am writing an ORM. I am curious how friend relations are generally modeled. Are they duplicated relations in a link table with each user an owner of his friend relations, or is there an introduction of a mutually owned relation, where the orm looks up relation links where the relation owner's id can be in the child field of the relation link table?

Comment: An example might be helpful to understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen an ORM doing your "mutually owned relation" because it would only work for readonly scenarios but ORM is typically for readwrite. i would model them [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10834450/671619)